# Close material dialog from shared service

Tags: angular

In my Angular 8 app I use `angular-material dialog` to do the CRUD operations.
If I want to close the dialog in component from the same component, I set ref in that constructor to name of dialog component

```
constructor(
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)
public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AssingTrialRoleComponent>,  //AssingTrialRoleComponent name of class
private store: Store<fromStore.State>
) {
```

and for close, I call `this.dialogRef.close();` in same component

But now, I add `@ngrx/store`, and in `@effect` I check for error or success and call a shared notification service to show a notification. From this shared notification service, I want a close dialog.3

```
  map(
      () => new actions.LoadUsers(),
      this.notificationService.success("Success, dialog is closed"), 
    ),
    catchError(err => of(this.notificationService.warn(err.error.message)))
   )
```

If `catchError` is triggered, dialog box need to stay open, if `success` I need to close the dialog from my shared notification service.

here is my notification service

```
export class NotificationPopUpServiceService {
constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

config: MatSnackBarConfig = {
   duration: 3000,
   horizontalPosition: "right",
   verticalPosition: "top"
 };

success(msg) {
   this.config["panelClass"] = ["notification", "success"];
   this.snackBar.open(msg, "", this.config);
   this.dialogRef.close();    <-- this is where I need to close dialog 
}

warn(msg) {
   this.config["panelClass"] = ["notification", "warn"];
   this.snackBar.open(msg, "", this.config);
}
}
```

I have multiple dialog boxes on the same app, and I want somehow know in shared service in which component they need to close dialog...

If I trigger this service in `user.component`, close this dialog in `user.component`, if I trigger service in `company.component` close this dialog....etc....

Is there any way to close modal from another service/component?

thnx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the DI by constructor of NotificationPopUpServiceService in each component is the solution,

And inside your service :

```
export class NotificationPopUpServiceService {
constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

config: MatSnackBarConfig = {
   duration: 3000,
   horizontalPosition: "right",
   verticalPosition: "top"
 };

success(msg) {
   this.config["panelClass"] = ["notification", "success"];
   this.snackBar.open(msg, "", this.config);
   this.closingDialogEvent('dialogName');    //is going to close the notification from a specific call
}

warn(msg) {
   this.config["panelClass"] = ["notification", "warn"];
   this.snackBar.open(msg, "", this.config);
}

closingDialogEvent(name:string) {
    this.dialogRef.close(name);
   console.log('event after closing dialog' );
  }
}
```

Comment: in `NotificationPopUpServiceService`, in constructor we need to set `public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<COMPONENT_NAME>` .How to define in your case constructor?

Comment: is your snackBar Material instance

Comment: I don't need to dismiss() snackBar, i need to close dialog

Comment: Are you looking for the component  who invokes  the success function ?

Comment: No, on success I only need to trigger this.dialogRef.close()

Comment: I understand, so why not using an other function that has the close() function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202266/discussion-between-youssef-tounoussi-and-arter).